# Splitting a neural network in 2 microservices

Tags: tensorflow

I have a neural network, that is already trained locally that can detect objects in the scene.

But I have to split the neural network into 2 parts, let's say it has 16 layers, and I want to have one microservice handle the first 8 layers and give the output of the 8th layer to the next microservice and it takes the data from there and proceeds with the 9th layer (1st layer in the 2nd microservice).

Sending an image to the 1st microservice will give the result from the 2nd microservice, is this feasible using TensorFlow?

Comment: Yes, it is feasible. You can split the graph in two parts, setup the services and wire them up so one sends its output to the other. What do you currently have and what precise step are you having trouble with?

Comment: Actually I'm having trouble with having the data extracted from 8th layer and start the neural network from 9th layer in the next microservice. Do I need to retrain it, for example if I take the trained VGG16 network, can I adapt it to this problem without having to retrain it?

Comment: If you already have a full trained model, with the weights saved or "frozen" in the graph, you shouldn't need to retrain anything. You can evaluate a model up to one layer, take that result somewhere else, and evaluate a model from the same point to the end, as long as you load the model and weights properly in both parts (you can either have the full model in each service or split it and have only the necessary layers loaded).

Comment: Okay, thank you for the answers. Let me ask you another question, if I want to generalize this approach, for example given an NN architecture, it will split the workload into 2 microservices with the method given above.
Is it hard to deduce the architecture weights, layers from a saved NN model, I mean can I do it dynamically for any given NN model?

Comment: It is always technically possible to split a model however you want, but you have to know where to split (that is, the tensor or op names). If you use for example the estimator API, it may require some work to find that out, if you write "low-level" TensorFlow (create variables yourself and write operations in your own code) it should be fairly trivial. If it is a trained model you got from somewhere else, you have to get to know the model architecture and figure out or decide where to cut.